# Combining adjacent rows based on comparision of values from different colums

Tags: sql, group-by

I'd like to group adjacent rows in a table when these  rows contain equal values in different columns.

For example, having a `Date_Begin` and a `Date_End` column, these rows should be merged when the `Date_End` value of the previous row is equal to the `Date_Begin` of the next row (and the have the same `Category`).

```
Input table:
    ----------------------------------------------
    | Category  | Date_Begin | Date_End  | Count |
    ----------------------------------------------
    |     A     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-07-10|  10   |
    |     A     | 2018-07-10 | 2019-01-01|  20   |
    |     B     | 2019-01-01 | 2019-04-01|  30   |
    |     B     | 2019-05-01 | 2019-07-01|  15   |
    ----------------------------------------------
```

Preferably, `Date_Begin`, `Date_End` and `Count` are adjusted accordingly, so the result would look like this:

```
Result table:
    ----------------------------------------------
    | Catergory | Date_Begin | Date_End  | Count |
    ----------------------------------------------
    |     A     | 2018-01-01 | 2019-01-01|  30   |
    |     B     | 2019-01-01 | 2019-04-01|  30   |
    |     B     | 2019-05-01 | 2019-07-01|  15   |
    ----------------------------------------------
```

I've found out that I can use the WINDOW `fuction` to compare adjacent rows, but I'm confused how to make the comparison of different `columns` and finally merge them?

Comment: what is the logic for merging `Date_begin` and `Date_end`.

Comment: Add the row (B, 2019-08-10, 2019-08-20, 15) to the sample data and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: I updated the example. Hopefully, it's clearer now that rows should be merged only if  `Date_End` value of the previous row is equal to the `Date_Begin` of the next row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands.  You can solve it by finding where the islands start -- say by using `lag()` and then using a cumulative sum (to identify the groups) and aggregation:

```
select category, grp, min(date_start), max(date_end),
       sum(count)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_date_end >= date_start then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by category order by date_start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date_end) over (partition by category order by date_start) as prev_date_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by category, grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function `max(),min() and sum()`

```
select category, min(date_begin),max(date_end),sum(count)
from table
group by category
```

Comment: _these rows should be merged when the Date_End value of the previous row is equal to the Date_Begin of the next row_.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using `aggregation` and `group by`

```
select category,min(Date_Begin),max(date_end),sum(count) as cnt
from tablename
group by category
```

Comment: _these rows should be merged when the Date_End value of the previous row is equal to the Date_Begin of the next row_

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  select category,min(Date_Begin),max(date_end),sum(count) as cnt from tablename group by category
```